# string operator and valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

I having some problem with correctly write method:
Edited i wrote new probably good

```
void operator += ( const string& s )
{
    size_t newLen = len + s.len;
    char    *tmpStr = new char [newLen+1];
    size_t i = 0;
    for(i;i<len;i++)
        {tmpStr[i] = p[i];}
    for(size_t j=0;j<s.len;j++)
    {
    tmpStr[i] = s[j];
    i++;
    }
    delete []p;
    p = tmpStr;
    len = newLen;
    p[len] = '\0';
}
```

Valgrind return me, i got some error and 1 memory leak

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==10152==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==10152==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 4 frees, 73,747 bytes 
allocated

==10152== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10152==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10152==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10152==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10152==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==10152==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10152== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are 
not shown.
==10152== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-
kinds=all

==10152== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10152== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I tried it for:

```
string s2 = "hello";
string s3 = "abc";
s3 += s2;
```

And my next question is how write, any idea what i have to do?

```
void operator += ( char c );
```

Here you are my constructor:

```
string( )
  : len{0},
    p{ nullptr }   
{ }

string( const char* s )
  : len{ strlen(s) },
    p{ new char[ len ] }
{
  for( size_t i = 0; i < len; ++ i )
     p[i] = s[i]; 
}

string( const string& s )
  : len{ s. len },
    p{ new char[ len ] }
{
  for( size_t i = 0; i < len; ++ i )
     p[i] = s.p[i]; 
}
```

Its correct: Leak memory still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks

Comment: Why `+8`? Can you explain that?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: the pointer of the internal string of `s`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem im not sure what i should add there i tried just it.

Answer (score 0):

The two errors pointed out make me think that `strcpy` is going over the allocated memory for the buffer of your internal `string` type. (since it's going after 5 bytes for `"hello"` and 3 bytes for `"abc"`).

`strcpy` is an unsafe operation, it keeps going until it finds a `\0` terminator. Now it seems that your internal buffer for your `string` type is not considering this, suppose something like

```
char data[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

This won't work for strcpy since there is no `\0`. Show us how you construct a `string` instance.

Now that you've edited the question the problem is clear, your constructor doesn't reserve the space nor it is placing the NUL terminator at the end of the `char[]` so standard stdlib functions are not working properly, try something like:

```
string( const char* s )
  : len{ strlen(s) },
    p{ new char[ len+1 ] }
{
  for( size_t i = 0; i < len; ++ i )
     p[i] = s[i]; 
  p[len] = '\0';
}
```

The difference here is that you are allocating `len+1` character for your buffer and placing `\0` in the last element of the array.

This terminator will work for stdlib functions so that they'll know where to stop. Now `strcpy` will properly work when finding the terminator.

Comment: so how  should I calculate that how many memory i need allocate?

Comment: So the problem is probably in his constructor, it's not putting a trailing null in `p`.

Comment: @Barmar: yes, the problem is probably in the constructor, this is the trivial deduction here but I'm just guessing.

Comment: The `+=` is copying the null byte, because `strcpy()` copies that. And `+8` leaves enough additional space for the null byte (all that's really needed is `+1`).

Comment: @xarix Post your constructor functions, and we can help you fix the root cause.

Comment: Thats look my constructor string( ): len{0},p{ nullptr }   {}

Comment: @Barmar: yes `strcpy` is copying that but the problem is that I don't think there is any NUL terminator in both `s2` or `s3` because he's not placing it when constructing the `string` instances. So `strcpy` goes over the buffer and here is where valgrind complains.

Comment: @xarix We need to see the constructor `string(char *)` that gets used when you write `string s2 = "hello";`

Comment: @Barmar: exactly as I've guessed in my "something like constructor" ;)

Comment: @Jack i added in my first post any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor isn't putting a trailing null byte in the `p` array, which is needed for any `strXXX()` functions. You need to add `1` to the `len` when allocating the array. Then use `strcpy()` to initialize the `p` array, which will copy all the characters and the null byte.

```
string( const char* s )
  : len{ strlen(s) },
    p{ new char[ len+1 ] }
{
  strcpy(p, s);
}

string( const string& s )
  : len{ s. len },
    p{ new char[ len + 1 ] }
{
  strcpy(p, s.p);
}
```

Also, the `+=` function needs to check if `p == nullptr`, and not call `strcpy()` in that case.

```
void operator += ( const string& s )
{
    size_t newLen = len + s.len;
    if (newLen == 0) { // Appending empty string to empty string, nothing to do
        return;
    }
    char *tmpStr = new char [newLen+1];
    if (p) {
        strcpy(tmpStr, p);
    }
    if (s.p) {
        strcpy(tmpStr + len, s.p);
    }
    delete []p;
    p = tmpStr;
    len = newLen;
}
```

Comment: @xarix: yes you can but you need to manually put the terminator, check my answer.

Comment: @xarix Why are you OK with using `strcpy()` in the `+=` function, but not the constructors?

Comment: @Barmar I have got witten code witch i have to complete so i dont want change that constructor.

Comment: @xarix: if you can't change the constructor this means that you can't assume that terminator is present so you can't use `strcpy` at all in `operator+=` but you need to make it manually.

Comment: @Jack so i have to write to 2 loops which first add 1 word to new string and second which add after this first word?

Comment: @xarix: exactly, and probably you have to write you own version of `operator<<(ostream& out, const string& s)` since trying to print directly the internal buffer yields the same problem because all functions assume the presence of the terminator.

Comment: @Jack ok i did it. What now i have to write in  void operator += ( char c );

Comment: @Jack and what with still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks and still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks its correct?